# Is there a limit for size of hypertable cell values?

Tags: bigdata, hypertable

I wonder if there is a limit for size of cell values in hypertable. I didn't found it in documentations so please share your experience if you ever tried to store big binary values in ht.

Answer (score 1):

4gb

According to: http://vschart.com/compare/apache-hive/vs/hypertable

I havn't seen in in the documentation either.